# How to customize Mpmoviewplayer size and fit that to collectionview cell

Tags: objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, uicollectionviewcell

I am playing an video from document directory in the collection view using below code

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{

        if (indexPath.item==0) {

        NSURL *vedioURL;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];

        NSLog(@"files array %@", filePathsArray);

        //reverse the array
        //    NSArray* reversedArray = [[filePathsArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
        //    NSLog(@"%@",reversedArray);

        NSString *fullpath;

        for ( NSString *apath in filePathsArray )
        {
            fullpath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:apath];
            vedioURL =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullpath];
        }
        NSLog(@"vurl %@",vedioURL);

        MPMoviePlayerViewController *videoPlayerView = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:vedioURL];
        videoPlayerView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 60, 412,229);
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];
        [view addSubview:videoPlayerView.view];
        [self.view addSubview:view];
        [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerView];
        [videoPlayerView.moviePlayer play];


    }
```

When I click on the image video is playing,but I want that video to be played in same position in the same  cell.

Comment: @Hi Halfer  can you please five me some solution

Comment: Hi Naidu, apply [view setClipsToBounds:YES];

Comment: Should i change any thing in the above code

Answer (score 0):

```
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *videoPlayerView = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:vedioURL];
    videoPlayerView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 60, 412,229);
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];
    [view addSubview:videoPlayerView.view];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerView];
    [videoPlayerView.moviePlayer play];
    [view setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

Comment: it will present the full screen  when i use this   [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:View]; it is coustamizing the size

Comment: the problem is the video is not comprising only the size is comprising

Comment: UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];  instead of the i have image in collection view cell can we play this vide in that image view   [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:cell imageview];

Comment: how to acess  the image view object declared in the collectionview cell the didselect item at indexpath

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {

@try {


    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // A safe check before going to access sibview.
    if ([cell.contentView.subviews count] > 0) 
    {
      // Find your imageview here
    }
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Exception :%@",exception.debugDescription);
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Bro sorry for the delay  this  MPMoviePlayerViewController *videoPlayerView = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:vedioURL];
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];
    [view addSubview:videoPlayerView.view];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerView];
    [videoPlayerView.moviePlayer play];
    [view setClipsToBounds:YES]; in the collection view cell  now when i click the image the video have to play

Comment: The add a UIGesture to the image and detect the tap. Give every image a unique id and when the UIGesture responds there add your play method

Comment: one doubt is I will add images randomly in that 3 image one is video first frame image when ever notification center  fires one image will add to the collection view cell  if that image is added to the collection view cell the video have to play in the cell,how to do that it same like instagram recording video and add it to the timeline

Comment: On which image you want to tap?

Comment: video first frame image,but all the images is adding to the same array

Comment: Do one things, add a tap gesture on the video thumbnail and get the responder differently. Forget about didselect

Comment: dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [assetLibrary writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:recordedFile
                                         completionBlock:
         ^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ if (error != nil) {  }    else {
                     title = @"Saved!";
                     message = nil;}{save alert  NSLog(@"%@",recordedFile);

Comment: i am recording the video the output is in the form of url and i am saving it

Comment: How to do that bro

Answer (score 0):

Tap gesture

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = 
[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                        action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
singleFingerTap.delegate = self;
[yourimageview addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
```

Try the following code:

```
conform the <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> to your class.
```

then add this delegate Method:

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

}
```

Comment: I know how to use tabgusters brother,i Have one idea but i dontknow how implement it can you help me out,now I have the recored video full output and i tested it the video is playing,now I have the path,now i will pass this path to the time line,now in the time line i have video url how to play the url using - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath,

Comment: You need a full screen player or small?

Comment: small i.e video must same size pf the cell when i scroll the video have to scroll with the collection view cell

Comment: Then add a MPMoviePlayerViewController on the didselect part at that place/frame where you have the imageView

Comment: we can do that bro but the requirement is like i the facebook  the video will play know like that.same i have to do

Comment: Add MPMoviePlayerViewController in every cell and then play when you get the tap

Comment: how to do that,we should not tab it have to play automatically

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066713/how-do-i-play-video-autoplay-in-uitableviewcell-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

MPMoviePlayerViewController is deprecated after iOS 9.
I think the better approach be to go with AVFoundation.
Here is the code snippet for you.

```
    NSURL *vedioURL = [NSURL URLWithString:
                       @"path for your video file"];
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:vedioURL];
    // create a player view controller
    AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
    controller.player = player;
    controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 40, 320 , 300);
    [player play];
    // show the view controller
    [self addChildViewController:controller];
    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
```

Note:- It won't play youtube videos, as it only plays movie files. To play other files you can use webview or may use some youtube parser to play youtube files with AVFoundation.

Comment: Yes, You need to use AVFoundation Framework and AVKit

Comment: can you please go through this question and if find any solution let me know

Comment: I have posted the solution for you using AVPlayerViewController. It will show in the frame which you will specify. And if you still want to use MPMoviePlayerViewController, then this is for full screen. Just use MPMoviePlayerController

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848142/paly-video-in-the-collection-view-cell-like-the-videos-playing-in-the-facebook-a  please go through question the link and let me know

Comment: I want play it the collection view cell which is having some images